# Vite restarting server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite, .env

I can't create .ENV file and run vite project
i got infinite loop

here is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define:{
    'process.env.VITE_KEY':JSON.stringify(process.env.VITE_KEY)
  }
})
```

```
1:52:04 PM [vite] .env changed, restarting server...
X [ERROR] The build was canceled
```

but if i delete .ENV file i can run my project

I try to create new project but it not work

Comment: Try `import 'dotenv/config'` instead of `import dotenv from 'dotenv'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon that the reason your server was restarting was due to a crash, because `process.env.VITE_KEY` was `undefined` and, I guess, vite doesn't accept undefined values:

```
define:{
  'process.env.VITE_KEY':undefined
}
```

By doing `import dotenv from 'dotenv'`, you're not actually injecting the values from your `.env` file ([docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv?activeTab=readme)).

What you need to do is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import 'dotenv/config'
// or you can do this:
// import { config } from 'dotenv'
// config({ path: '.env' })

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define:{
    'process.env.VITE_KEY':JSON.stringify(process.env.VITE_KEY)
  }
})
```